# Clone folder from ftp to disk and disk to ftp

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i have a ftp with a folder named fotos, i need to create a script to use as a cron that get all files from the folder but dont replace if exist and in the end put in the ftp server fotos folder all that dont exist in the server but exist in disk.

I will try to explain a little better

ftp -> folder Fotos -> several folders with subfolders with fotos and videos
disk -> drive j: -> folder Fotos -> several folders with subfolders with fotos and videos

i need to do ftp -> disk and disk -> ftp without replace because i already have 50.000 files in there.

this is what im working on

```
import os
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP()
server = "ftp.server.com"
user = "user"
passw = "password"
path = "Fotos"
path2 = "J:\FOTOS"

ftp.connect(server, 21, timeout=15)
login_response = ftp.login(user, passw)
ftp.encoding = "utf-8"
ftp.cwd(path)

print(ftp.getwelcome())

for ftp_file in ftp.nlst():

    print("checking " , ftp_file)

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ftp_file):
        for name in files:
            print(name)
            if name !="Thumbs.db":
                print(name)

    if ftp_file not in os.listdir(path2):
        print('Downloading file: %s' , ftp_file)
        #ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ ftp_file ,open(ftp_file,'wb').write,rest=0)
    else:
        print("existe")



print("end")
```

It connects to the ftp then print ('checking ', '1. Folder') and nothing more.

Could this be because of the number of files in the folder?

if i just add this

```
for ftp_file in ftp.nlst():
    print("checking " , ftp_file)
```

it prints all the folders names

Comment: This task screams for `rsync`. Concerning your question, you could answer this yourself by running it on a folder with just a handful of files. In any case, please extract a [mcve], which shows exactly what fails, stripped of any code that isn't even executed. Also, provide the output it produces. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: lol, my bad :( searched for rsync but it seems it dont work with ftp.